# lpr saturation not working (CUPS)

Tags: cups, lpr

it's a simple question, I just want to know why this command is not working for me.

I'm using on terminal this:

`lpr -o saturation=0 nameFile.png`

This should print in black & white but this always is printing in color. Maybe i need to install something and I don't know, but I can't find a solution.

Someone knows what I should do? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It may help if you try

`lp -o saturation=0 nameFile.png`

or

`lp -d name-printer -o saturation=0 nameFile.png`